# Trees, Graphs, and Dual Graphs ("Basic Topology" by M. A. Armstrong)

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory

This question may be a little lengthy and contains two images for reference - apologies in advance.

For background, **Euler's theorem:**

Let $P$ be a polyhedron which satisfies:

a. Any two vertices of $P$ can be connected by a chain of edges.

b. Any loop on $P$ which is made up of straight line segments (not necessarily edges) separates $P$ into two pieces.

Then $v-e+f=2$ for $P$.

The book I'm using for self-studying topology begins with an outlined proof of Euler's Theorem, and I'm struggling just a little understanding exactly what a dual graph is. I understand what a Tree and a Graph are when representing polyhedra, but I am not grasping the definition given for a dual graph quite right. For any polyhedron, one could sketch more than one appropriate tree, or graph, right? Would this provide different possible dual graphs for a single polyhedron?

Alongside this, in Figure 1.5 shown in an image below, I can see $\Gamma$ represented on $P$ quite clearly, but I'm not really seeing the Tree, $T$. The only bolded edges are the two on the left, but that leaves out the far-right vertex, correct? Unless the dashed edge is also a part of the tree, Making it $4$ vertices with $3$ connecting edges. How could I come up with such a dual, $\Gamma$, given the tree perhaps layed flat on a plane without its context - wouldn't it be the same structure as the dual graph?

These questions may be stated incorrectly, or may very well just not make sense. If any further clarification is needed, feel free to comment.

[image: Basis of a Tree, Graph, and Dual Graph, "Basic Topology" by M. A. Armstrong, 3]

[image: Figure 1.5, "Basic Topology" by M. A. Armstrong, 4]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For any polyhedron, one could sketch more than one appropriate tree, or graph, right? Would this provide different possible dual graphs for a single polyhedron?

Yes, the proof only requires us to choose *some* tree $T$ and the corresponding $\Gamma$, it does not specify which.

> I'm not really seeing the Tree, $T$. The only bolded edges are the two on the left, but that leaves out the far-right vertex, correct? Unless the dashed edge is also a part of the tree, making it 4 vertices with 3 connecting edges.

Yes, the dashed edge is included as well (the three bold edges in the diagram form the tree).

> How could I come up with such a dual, $\Gamma$, given the tree perhaps layed flat on a plane without its context - wouldn't it be the same structure as the dual graph?

In general, a graph may have multiple [dual graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_graph), but we construct $\Gamma$ in a specific way corresponding to the polyhedron $P$ -- namely as the graph with vertex set equal to the set of faces of $P$ and edge set equal to the set of edges of $P$ that are not part of $T$.

[This section of the wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_graph#Spanning_trees) might also be of interest to you. We begin with two graphs -- $G_v$, which has vertex set equal to the set of vertices of $P$ and edges between vertices which have an edge between them in $P$, and $G_f$, which has vertex set equal to set of faces of $P$ and edges between faces which are adjacent to each other. More or less by definition, $G_v$ and $G_f$ are duals to each other. Consequently, the edges of the two graphs can be partitioned into two spanning trees ($T$ and $\Gamma$), which extend to all the vertices and faces of the graph but never cross each other.

For example, in the context of $P$ being a tetrahedron as in the figure (forgive the messy drawing),

[image]

The black graph is $G_v$, the red graph is $G_f$, the thick edges in $G_v$ form $T$, and the thick edges in $G_f$ form $\Gamma$.

The central three faces of the graph represent the "upward" faces $A,B,C$ of the tetrahedron, and the outer face represents the "downward" face $D$.